# 2023 BMW x3 m40i “Pre-mature” Oil Change

Tags: bmw, oil-change, break-in

Just got my first BMW (x3 m40i) last summer, brand new. The first oil change is due @ 14k km (mind blown). Completed the manual-recommended break-in and now stuck wondering if I should do an oil change prior to the scheduled one, maybe at 7k or so?

Read bunch of controversial opinions on the web, about “special” break-in oils and having to keep them in until the recommended oil change. The others claim it is a must for m type vehicles at even much earlier interval, like 1200miles.

So asking for some advice given I own and keep my cars for 8-10 years on average and also this car is a daily short distance heavy traffic commuter, so less highway.

Answer (score 2):

Modern engines need very little break-in.  The 2023 BMW's are no expection.  "Special" break-in oils are only found in racing applications.  Here is what your [Owner's Manual](https://x3.xbimmers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1863628) recommends for the '23 x3 m40i (p.310):

**Engine, transmission, and axle drive**

**Up to 1,200 miles/2,000 km**
Do not exceed the maximum engine and road speed:
-> For gasoline engine 4,500 rpm and 100 mph/160 km/h.
Avoid full throttle or kickdown under all circumstances

**From 1,200 miles/2,000 km**
The engine and vehicle speed can gradually be increased.

==============================================================

Changing the oil @ 7k miles can do no harm.  In fact, it's commonplace here in the U.S.A.  Happy motoring!